# How would two generational ships traveling at point eight cee communicate with each other?

Tags: space-travel, communication, electromagnetism

In my story, I have two huge generation ships racing each other to another star system. Assume they are on an exactly parallel path, neck-and-neck, about one astronomical unit apart. They are traveling at exactly the same speed - point eight cee. They know the other ship is there, somewhere. They launched at the same time, although from separate in-system facilities.

The form of drive is important. They are traveling in a modified Alcubierre drive - that is, using the vernacular, they are in a space-time bubble that preserves relativistic effects within the ships. The drive creates a low-pressure space-time area in front, and a high pressure space-time area behind. The drives also interplay with the Higgs field to reduce the effects of inertial mass. Thus, the bubble is effectively 'surfing' through space, being pushed by the high pressure from behind. Sort of like an airplane stays in the air. There is no intention to use the system to go faster than the speed of light, just close to it.

Because of this, the ships are huge. They have huge fusion reactors, and a complete physics laboratory. Power is not an issue. They each carry tens of thousands of people, and have academic institutions that train new physicists born on the ships. Think in terms of a complete city. Knowledge and the ability to build new equipment is not a problem.

The question is, traveling at such extreme speeds, wrapped up in a bubble, can they communicate with each other? If so, then how?

Because they are adversaries, there are no entanglement possibilities between them.

Some additional background to consider - light takes about 500 seconds to go one AU. The trick is not in the relative speed between the ships, but that they are both traveling at point 8 cee relative to where the light was first emitted. That is, there would be a Doppler effect as the light arrived at the other ship.

The point of protecting the inhabitants from relativistic effects is that I sincerely doubt biological processes could function in the relativistic effects of point 8 cee.

For consideration: Would there be a null point in the bubble between the front negative pressure and the rear positive pressure that could be used?

A point of physics. When you project a beam of light from a spaceship, the point of origin effectively drops dead. That is, the beam origin does not gain or loose momentum from the spaceship. At the point in space-time where you 'drop' it, it stays there. Perfectly dead in the - well - space-time. The ship continues on. It does not 'follow' or 'trail' the ship. If you beam it behind you, then you travel away from the originating point of the beam, the point of origin just hangs there, and the speed of the light is determined relative to that 'dead drop'. Not the speed of the ship. Not the speed of anything around it. If it is a completely uni-directional laser beam, and it comes out the extreme rear of the ship, the ship occupants will never be able to detect it unless they come around. Baring gravity, it goes in a perfectly straight line from the original point of origin in space-time.

**Please Note** I use point 8 cee because **c** is constant in all inertial frames, but the speed of a spaceship certainly isn't. I use cee as a unit of speed, as in miles per hour.

Comment: Their relative speed is ≈0±0.1c or sth like that, right?

Comment: Their relative speed to each other is zero.

Comment: Just a little nipticking : why wouldn't you preserve relativistic effects within the ship ? The only effect of relativity in there is that the trip will seem faster to them so why not keep it that way ? Also, what are "the effects of inertial mass" to you ?

Comment: The Alcubierre drive has some effects which speak against your idea, in particular the bubble is disconnected from the universe outside, so there is no possibility of signals passing to the other ship, regardless of how close or far away it is. This also makes navigation somewhat.....challenging

Comment: @Keelhaul Time dilation is not the only concern at that speed. Mass also has relativistic effects, as does distance.I really don't think that life could exist anywhere near the speed of light. Biology would work very different.

Comment: @Thucydides I understand I am taking some liberties with the Alcubierre drive. That's why the qualifier 'based on'. But yes, that is why describing the drive is crucial. The signalling method would seem to have to be outside the bubble somehow. It also merits consideration that the bubble is NOT traveling FTL. Does that allow a conduit through the bubble? Since anything on the outside is not traveling at FTL, no contradiction with relativity.

Comment: @Justin Thyme Do not forget that speed is relative. Sure your mass is somewhat different from your rest mass seen from, say, your home planet. But the entire ship is at rest relative to itself, crew included. There is ABSOLUTELY no difference inside your ship as everything in it travels at the same speed. Again, speed is always relative to something else. When we say "cruise at 0.8c", it's always implied "relative to departure" or "relative to arrival". So, nothing would work different (except for the threat of high-energy impacts from the medium you travel through).

Comment: So, just to clarify: the Alcubierre drive is basically a plot device to remove the necessity of calculating the difference in elapsed time at the starting point from which the ships launched versus the elapsed time for the ships? It may be simpler to just remove the drive since you are not theorizing about FTL and calculating time based on speed isn't actually that bad.

Comment: @JBiggs It serves two purposes. One is to create the delta v necessary to achieve point 8 cee (surfing, as it were, using the pressure difference  'squeeze' to push it forward without reaction mass, like an airplane wing stays up without any reaction mass push downwards as required by a helicopter) and the second is to ensure that mass does not approach infinity as the speed increases. Sort of (in the vernacular) to counter the Lorentz factor. Einstein was perhaps close, but Planck was even closer. We are even still closer today with more up-to-date models.

Comment: @Keelhaul 'traveling at point 8 cee' is traveling at point 8 cee period. Not relative to any other point but the speed of light. If you started from a ship that was traveling, say, point 2 cee, you are not traveling at point 8 cee PLUS point 2 cee, you are going point 8 cee. That is, point 6 cee faster than the ship you started from. At speeds approaching cee, the velocities are not purely additive.

Comment: There is no "not relative to any other point", and no "relative to the speed of light". Speed IS relative. An object is moving at .8c RELATIVE to another object (you go .8c away from your departure and .8c towards your arrival). In your example, the first ship is traveling at .2c relative to, say, the Earth. The second ship is traveling in the same direction at .8c relative to the first ship. Does that mean it is traveling à 1c relative to Earth ? No, because of relativity and the Lorentz tranformations (look it up), the second ship is moving at around .86c from Earth. It is ALWAYS relative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70884/discussion-between-justin-thyme-and-shadowzee).

Comment: Well, in fact, since I'm bored at work (holydays are pretty dull), I did ask the question on physics.se :D ! If anyone is interested, here it is : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376722/communication-between-two-ships-moving-at-relativistic-speed

Comment: @JustinThyme Everything these other users have been trying to explain to you is exactly correct. More modern theories have not displaced relativity in favor of a static reference frame. Technologies you use every day explicitly rely on relativity, and their continued functioning is, I think, pretty compelling evidence that the idea that Einstein has been left in the dust is pure hogwash. Please, link to any sort of academic journal supporting your claims.

Comment: @Catgut How about the fact that since at least 1980 only one Nobel prize in physics has been awarded to a physicist doing research even remotely connected to Einstein (gravitational waves) but there is a slew of them in the field of quantum physics and cosmology. And the fact that more and more articles like [What Einstein Got Wrong About the Speed of Light](http://time.com/4083823/einstein-entanglement-quantum/) are revealing that Planck was the genius, Einstein was just a minor blip in the grand scheme of physics.

Comment: ctd And, of course, the fact that Einstein's theories never lead to a new revolution in computer technology, the way Quantum Computing has. The world of physics lost 50 good years by chasing the dead ends of Einstein. His concept that everything is relative lead physics down the garden path for far too long.

Comment: ctd But here is a reference to a book that pretty much puts the nail in the coffin of relativity. [Fields of Color The Theory that Escaped Einstein](http://www.quantum-field-theory.net/chap-1/) Yet unfortunately, it minimizes the significance of Planck in Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: ...You realize that, in Fields of Color author Rodney Brooks' [own words](https://www.quora.com/What-do-mainstream-physicists-think-about-Rodney-Brooks-Fields-of-Color-book-about-QFT/answer/Rodney-Brooks-3), Quantum Field Theory is an attempt to *reconcile* relativity and quantum mechanics, accepting both as correct descriptions of their respective environments? Still waiting on as little as a journal citation for relativity being completely wrong as you seem to claim.

Comment: @Catgut Yes, I agree that there are a lot of theorists who are trying to reconcile QM with GR,. Precisely my point the GR is wasting so much time and effort of some brilliant minds in attempts to reconcile them. There is no compelling reason to keep GR, except that it would have to be recognized that all of the time, effort, money, education, and resources put into it have been wasted. Too many people have a vested interest in their educational studies to abandon it. So much re-learning would have to occur,. Fortunately, China has not been wrapped up in GR as extensively as the West.

Comment: ctd See [Was Einstein wrong? Chinese physicist Wu Yueliang claims universe flat not curved, created by ‘big break’ instead of ‘big bang](http://www.scmp.com/tech/science-research/article/1903684/was-einstein-wrong-chinese-physicist-wu-yueliang-claims) for instance. The basic incongruity between QM and GR is the concept that GR still is hung up about everything being relative, that there is no 'foundation', but Field Theory demands a universal field on which everything is 'mapped'. Everything is relative to this field.

Comment: Are you asking a worldbuilding question, or advocating for your own view of physics? (Which runs contrary to current science, which makes the question rather difficult to answer.)

Comment: @Elukka The question is clear and precise. I am looking for an answer which is based on the laws of physics. Effects on mass and energy as speeds approach the speed of light can be deduced from the equation e = mc^2, which came much before Einstein and General Relativity. Time dilution can be deduced from Maxwell's equations and electromagnetism. These I have no problems with. No need for GR. But this hand-waving magical fantasy that cee is the-same-but-different between inertial frames of reference is just, well, irrelevant. The constant cee is relative only to a universal frame of reference.

Comment: ctd Postulating that something will happen if I reference the speed of a spaceship to one planet, but something different will happen if I reference the speed to that of a spaceship traveling at another speed, and there is no issue if I reference the speed to a ship travelling parallel to and at the same speed as my ship, but look out if I reference the speed of my ship to one going just as fast in the other direction? Just senseless. THAT makes the question unanswerable. I am not traveling faster than the speed of light if I am traveling beside a ship going the same speed as I am?

Answer (score 10):

### They totally can

They may travel at extreme speed relative to their departure/arrival/medium in-between (think space dust), but relative to each other, they are mostly immobile. So any communication device able to cross 1AU (like a simple radio or laser beam) would do it, their "speed" doesn't matter.

However, the Alcubierre bubble is another story. Since it's a fictionnal device it's hard to predict, but since it's your story, do what is convenient for you. My intuition would be that the bubble effectively distorts the signal, kind of like how light is distorted by the refractive index of water, especially if the water is not still. But I believe that, using this bubble as a drive, your colonists have it fine tuned and can precisely compute the distortion effect, and reverse it to get a clear signal.

So, speed is not an issue and the bubble problem can be circumvented. The fact that you state "They know the other ship is there, somewhere" would tend to assume they don't know exactly where the other ship is but let's face it : at 1AU apart, with really big ships, it's not that hard to find each other. And once they do, they won't lose track of the other ship. Therefore aiming a radio signal is not an issue either.

Comment: At point 8 cee, even light would not traverse the distance fast enough, methinks, to actually hit the other space ship, unless it was aimed at where the ship WOULD be. It takes light almost 500 seconds to travel one AU. How would the Doppler effect change the signal? The receiving ship would be traveling away from the point at which the light were emitted from the sending ship. I am trying to get a handle on what kind of distortion would occur as the signal goes through the bubble. Would there be a 'null' node exactly at the center, where the front negative wave meets the back positive wave?

Comment: I know this can be hard to grasp at first, but your ships are immobile relative to each other. There is indeed a 8 minute delay to cross the 1AU of distance, but no doppler effect, and no aiming forward. That would be the case if one sheep was moving relative to the other, but they are not.

Comment: Imagine being in a car, with a friend in another car, both going at the same speed in the same direction on a highway. Also imagine there is no atmospheric drag (and that the lack of atmosphere didn't kill you or stopped the engine, bear with me^^). Then you could throw a ball to your mate exactly as if you were still. Erase everything around you from your vision, the trees rushing on the sides, the road markings ... now you just visualize two cars at rest. Your cars are going away from your departure and close the distance to your arrival, but to each other (and to you), they are immobile.

Comment: @JustinThyme The fact that both ships are moving at 0.8c relative to *Earth* has no bearing on the question. The ships aren't moving *relative to each other.* The 1 AU distance results in an 8 minute one-way delay (16 minute round trip, assuming instantaneous reply). That's it. If you want to debate the point further, then I'll let you in on a little known secret: there is no experiment you can perform within your reference frame to determine if your reference frame is moving.

Comment: @Draco18s They are going at point 8 cee relative to the speed of light, NOT to earth. Relative to earth, they could be going slower or faster. But since earth is not going at anything like point 2 cee, the additive velocity will never exceed cee. it CAN'T. And, actually, there IS an experiment that can determine if you're reference frame is moving.

Comment: @JustinThyme Nope, not how physics works. All velocities are relative to to some reference frame (e.g. Earth). There is no universal cosmic background reference frame from which light is moving at c. Light moves at c *in all inertial reference frames.* Also, if there is such an experiment, link it. Because if its true, you've [proven known science wrong](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364015/29541).

Comment: @Justin Thyme I suggest you do some research, "relative to the speed of light" is a nonsense. You have a velocity relative to a reference point (for example : the Earth), not relative to a speed. That just doesn't make sense. And yes, nothing can go past the speed of light : but this is not contradicted by having multiple frames of reference, thanks to relativity and more particuarly the Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @Draco18s [Detecting Earth's Rotation Through Space Using a Large Area Sagnac Interferometer](http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/Sagnac/SagnacEarth.html) It's not science that is wrong. Maybe YOUR physics doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Keelhaul The speed of light in a vacuum is the speed of light in a vacuum. Not relative to ANYTHING. Unless you are claiming that it is the universe that is moving, and not the light. The speed of light is the same speed, if it is in absolutely empty space, devoid of any reference points. It is, in fact, the universal reference to ALL speeds.

Comment: @JustinThyme Rotational motion is also known as "acceleration" within the earth-surface reference frame. Acceleration is definitely visible via experimentation. It is, however, not the same as inertial motion. *`the difference corresponds to the net rotation of the loop with respect to some external preferred frame, that frame might alternatively be referred to as 1) the non-rotating gravitational frame of the earth, or 2) what is commonly referred to as the frame of the "fixed stars".`* The "fixed stars" are not an absolute reference frame. Our local group is moving with respect to other grps

Comment: @Draco18s Since everything in the universe is accelerating, thanks to the big bang and dark matter, there ARE no ' PURE inertial frames of reference' except in the theories and the models. There are only 'ALMOST inertial frames of reference'. Since everything is accelerating, then the movement of everything can be detected. But the 'fixed stars' do not need to be observed. You asked for an experiment that allowed you to detect movement just by observing within your frame of reference. You originally made no reference to INERTIAL reference frame.

Comment: @JustinThyme https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NBK1.png

Comment: @Draco speed of light is not relative. It's always 1c (in vacuum) no matter how you choose reference frame. So not all speeds are relative. Only the ones less than 1c are ;) that said you are generally right, ships can treat each other as stationary pretty well.

Comment: @Mołot I never said the speed of light was relative.

Comment: @Justin Thyme YES, speed of light is always the same regardless of reference point. But your ships are not moving at the speed of light. Their speed is of .8c relative to Earth, 0 relatve to each other, and may be .5c relative to Tatooine. The light beam they'll use for comunication wil travel at c as seen from the ships (crossing the distance in around 8 minutes), and it will also travel at c as seen from Earth or Tatooine thanks to time dilation. My whole point had always been that being at rest relative to each other, the communicatioon will suffer no shift at all.

Answer (score 4):

## Maybe.

Everything inside an Alcubierre bubble is causally disconnected from everything outside the bubble, but only if you're going faster than light. Since you mentioned that you're using subluminal velocities, you're not causally disconnected from the rest of the universe. You are surrounded by a bubble of compressed space-time, however, and that's going to give you some problems. It's easily observed that compressed space-time refracts light passing through it. This is going to pose some issues when you try to project something out of the bubble. Since this bubble is going to be concave around the transmitter, it's going to tend to diffuse any transmission out of the bubble, so the signal is going to have to be both extremely strong and very concentrated. It's also putting off some serious radiation from the front end, so you'll need to compete with that to get a signal out.

## But this is science *fiction*!

Well then, let's say that you can manage to get a signal out of the bubble. Making the problem worse, the universe has stuff in it [citation needed]. This is probably going to be a fairly lossy connection, so you're going to have to figure out a way to deal with interference and lost bits. These are surmountable problems.

---

## So actually, let's not use a transmitter inside our bubble at all!

I posted this answer too soon, and I've just thought of a fairly novel way to approach this. As I mentioned earlier in the post, the bubble is creating a great deal of radiation. Maybe we can harness that! Let's turn our entire ship into an AM transmitter! I'll be the first to admit I haven't slogged through the math on this one, but I'd put some money on the fact that increasing the speed of your bubble will increase the amount of radiation being emitted from the bubble. So if you can effectively modulate the speed of the ship, you can modulate the energy of the radiation!

Now once your message reaches the other ship, the problem posed by the bubble actually becomes a benefit! I can't speak to the actual shape of the bubble, but I'm betting it's roughly spherical (in the front that is). The back is under negative pressure, so that's going to mess with things, but if you can use the front of the bubble to refract the signal back in towards the ship, you may actually get some gain.

Beware that if you're looking for hard science, this last paragraph is rampant speculation, and I'd recommend you move over to the physics stack exchange to get some answers there.

Comment: But I am not going FTL. There is no disconnect with 'normal' relativity. Would there be a null point between the front and the back that would connect to 'normal'  space? I agree there would be a Doppler effect.

Comment: See the edit. After some further thinking, I was definitely too quick to judge this one.

Comment: "but the speed of light is constant, so you're actually going to have to point it way out ahead.". Nope, not at all. The speed of light is indeed constant relative to any observer, including your ships, so you'll just have to aim right to the other one. Remember that one of the core principle in relativity is that speed is always relative. The ships are immobile relative to each other, so we don't care about their speed relative to the orther things (like their departure and arrival).

Comment: Otherwise, juste because the earth is roaming at ludicrous speed relative to some distant galaxy, we would have to throw anything ahead taking in account this "speed". But wait ! We should also take in account another totally different speed from another galaxy ! What a nigthmare... That's why it doesn't work that way. Your ships go in the same direction with the same speed ? Then to all extents, we don't care what happens outside. Your ships can communicate fine.

Comment: @Keelhaul  Then how do you explain red shift in the light hitting us from distant galaxies?

Comment: The distant galaxies are moving away from us, they have a velocity relative to us, and that causes a redshift indeed. On the contrary, the ships are not moving relative to each other. You will see no redshift from a galaxy standing still relative to us.

Comment: Your answer is starting to take shape, and I am tending to like it. It hinges on their being a null point that is not a singularity - that is, it has enough width for a conduit. But I am also thinking about the quantum effects, and quantum tunneling, to get the message through. That is, the message is outside the bubble, then it is inside, without it going THROUGH.

Comment: @Keelhaul answer has been edited to remove the incorrect portion. Consider reading the rest, because that part was really a small portion of my full answer

Comment: @bendl Thank you, however I prefer not to step into the debate about the Alcubierre drive since I'm not very familiar with it, I leave it to you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, your edited version took out all the correct stuff. The original version was correct. The Doppler effect is real, and measurable. When we see light from galaxies just after the Big Bang we see them WHERE THEY WERE, not where they are, They have long since moved from that position. The beam of light didn't miraculously move with them as they moved, at their speed, it kept going along its original path. The galaxies moved away from it. And no, one will never get a good answer from the physics stack exchange. Going there is like reading Fox News for accurate information on America.

Comment: @JustinThyme we see them as the were because they are very far away from us, not because they are moving relative to us. And I wasn't really looking for an answer from the physics people, I was looking for a clarification of how the differences between the point of view of a stationary observer and the ships can be explained. It's just simply true that two objects with 0 relative velocity act as though stationary. The Doppler effect is definitely real, but it only applies when things are moving relative to each other, which the ships are not.

Comment: @bendl The fact is, light has no sideways momentum. If you shine a beam of light, it does not go  sideways. It has no mass. It has no inertia. It has no momentum. It does NOT take on the forward momentum of the spaceship. There is no 'inertial frame of reference' for light, or any energy beam, except the static non-moving quantum field. Light is always seen, from any inertial frame of reference, as traveling in this static massless field. Einstein so should have listened to Planck, instead of bull-headedly dismissing him. Einstein continued to think of everything, including light, as mass.

Comment: ctd Einstein continued to think of light as having inertia. Massless energy does not follow any rules of any inertial reference frame. It operates outside of and independent of any inertial reference frame. Only things that have inertia follow the rules if inertial reference frames. The velocity of light is not additive with the speed of the inertial object it is propagated from. It's velocity is only determined by propagation through an inertia-less non-moving static field.

Comment: ctd What is meant by 'light travels at the same speed in every inertial reference frame' means, is that when the ball was thrown on the train, it continues to stay on the train. It has gained the train.s momentum, But as soon as the beam of light is propagated, it no longer stays on the train. The train leaves it behind (if the train was traveling fast enough). Both the observer on the train and the observer on the ground see the light as being in its own, massless, inertia-less reference frame. The observer on the train says goodbye to the light beam.

Comment: ctd So, actually, does the observer on the ground eventually say goodbye, because the ground is in  its own inertial, mass reference frame.The observer on the ground will eventually say goodbye to the beam of light, if somehow the beam could be 'frozen' into some permanent massless inertia-less structure. The beam of light stays perfectly still. Everything around it with mass, inertia, and momentum  moves on, That frozen beam of light is the only thing that is NOT moving.

Answer (score 2):

**They can if you say they can.**

The [Alcubierre bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) is a mathematical solution consistent with the Einstein field equations, but that solution may not be physically meaningful. Even if it is, it requires negative energy to create, and we have never seen negative energy. Negative energy may not be possible within the laws of physics. There is so much uncertainty about how a real Alcubierre drive would work, that you can fill in a lot of the blanks however you like.

I can imagine that radio waves pass through the bubble without any issues. The two ships can have a high bandwidth connection, albeit with an 8 minute delay due to the 1 AU of distance.

I can imagine that the Alcubierre bubble scrambles all radio communications in or out. If we assume that the radio waves are transmitting a digital signal, the 1s and 0s might have to be very long and sent with a very powerful antenna to be received. Otherwise the radio signal gets lost in the radio noise. You could also say that the Alcubierre bubble gives off a lot of EM radiation (radio waves, micro-waves, light etc). This could limit the two ships to text messages as opposed to Skype calls.

I can imagine that the Alcubierre bubble completely destroys all conventional EM signals. If this is the case, you could use your warp drive to vibrate your bubble in something akin to morse code. The other ship could detect the vibrations and decode them into a text message. This sounds expensive, slow and risky, only to be used in a dire emergency.

Comment: I am not talking about the Alcubierre drive going FTL. It just has to go point 8 cee. The purpose in part is to reduce relativistic effects inside the bubble. Can life even EXIST going at that speed, otherwise?  I can envision that, somehow, the bubble could be intentionally vibrated in such a way as to be able to send a signal, but how does it get detected? Someone outside the bubble might detect it, but someone inside another bubble?

Comment: You don't need anything to protect from relativistic effects. There is no difference to life or anything else whether it is standing still or moving at 0.8c. Indeed, stating that raises the question of "standing still or moving at .8c relative to what?" There is no universal reference frame, so all speeds are relative to something else, which alone implies there can't really be a difference.

Comment: @Elukka Traveling at point 8 cee relative to the speed of light. The speed of light is the universal reference frame. Relativistic effects means that you can not have a beam of light traveling faster than the speed of light, so if the bubble is already going point 8 cee, the light beam can not travel faster than point 2 cee in the direction of travel. But if you take a bubble of space-time along with you, the light can travel at cee WITHIN that bubble in any direction. It just can't ESCAPE from that bubble going at the additive velocity of cee.

Comment: @Justin Thyme You just contradicted yourself when saying "the light beam can not travel faster than point 2 cee in the direction of travel". I though the speed of light was always c (and it is) ? Again, even if the ship is going .8c relative to the Earth, your light beam will go at c relative to both the Earth and your ship. Time dilation is a weird stuff, but it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

**You're using one mathematical concept that doesn't completely fit with our empirical universe, so let's use another.**

[Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) are theoretical particles that travel faster than the speed of light, which (I think) overcomes all the intrinsic problems associated with the Alcubierre drive.

**But what about causality?**

*Disclaimer: I am not a theoretical physicist.  If a PhD in physics suggests that what I'm about to say is hooey, I defer to their judgment.*

In the examples of communciation using Tachyons (such as the [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone)), the example is always communication between one relativistic position and one non-relativistic position... allowing (theoretically) the message to be received before it was sent.

However, I've not found (and didn't look hard for) an example of communiction between two relativistic positions.  In the case of your ship, *both ships are moving within the same intertial frame despite being physically disconnected.*  Due to this, causality should be preserved (IhopeIhopeIhope).

Comment: I am NOT traveling faster than the speed of light, No tachyons necessary. No worries about causality. Normal rules apply, except that I am enclosing the ship in a bubble that carries its own space-time inertial frame. That part you are correct in. Two issues that I can see remain: one is the Doppler effect, and the second is getting a signal in and out of the bubble. A beam of light sent from one spaceship does not travel with the spaceship. It continues on from its original starting point, A light beam has no inertia. It does not 'gain' momentum from the moving spaceship.

Comment: By the time it gets to the other spaceship, the other spaceship is about point 8 AU away from the starting point. That is some Doppler shift.

Comment: On a side note, one interesting theory has time going forward, but an an increasingly faster rate. Eventually, the limit is reached where you have instantaneous time throughout all eternity. Everything happens at once.

Comment: Mind you, I AM assuming that, at 1AU, the two ships are still within the light cone of each other. Otherwise, yes causality may be a factor. That, really, is related to the Doppler effect. If light can not breach the gap, given the speed of the ship away from the point of origin of the light, then yes causality could be a factor. That is some interesting math.

Comment: Ah!  The tachyons are necessary because you're losing bandwidth.  As you mention elsewhere, at .8c there's still .2c to work with, but that means you can only modulate the signal within that remaining 20%.  From a wave propogation point of view, that's a ton of loss.  But, introduce FTL tachyons and this entire issue vanishes.  (I wasn't suggesting that your ships were FTL.)

Comment: Okay, now I get it. You might be right. Again, the Doppler effect. I suppose tachyons could exist and be used in 'normal' space-time, so they can go faster than the light would normally allow, to transmit information between ships. Good point. And yes that would bring causality into play. Since information is being sent at the speed of tachyons, then it would be traveling faster than the speed of light, even though the ships would not be. But the information would never be received before it was sent.

Comment: No matter how fast the tachyons traveled, there would still be a forward time gap between transmission and reception. And they might conceivably go through the bubble. Let me think about that one.

Comment: @JBH It seems that this is a common misconception, but there is not .2c to work with, light will always travel at c as seen from anything. And since the ships are standing still relative to each other, there is no effect on light whatsoever. Maybe the Earth is traveling at .8c relative to another distant galaxy, but there is not need to aim forward when pointing a laser at someone.